# Slanted text with background box

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, typography, text

Hello fellow creatives!

I know this sounds like a stupid question, but this has been driving me insane for ages!

How do I achieve the following in adobe illustrator:

How do I create a slanted text look with a bordering box whilst maintaining its aspect ratio? I know this sounds confusing, so here is an image of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: This is what I am trying to create.]

Thanks in advance!
Stay creative!

Answer (score 3):

- Set type.
- Draw a box behind it
- Select box and type
- Use the **Shear Tool** - click once on one side of the box to set the origin, then click-drag at the *other* side of the box, hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> down and drag up or down.

[image]

There are a few other methods you could use, from the Free Transform Tool to Type on a Path to Envelopes and transform effects, but this is probably the most straightforward method.